# The border won't cover the background image

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me to bordered cover the image? I need this for my website culminating and theThe border won't fully cover my background

Here's the picture of it [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qj0D.jpg

Here my is html code

```
<div class="bg-container">

<img src="images/HD-High-Tech-Background.jpg" alt="High Tech- 
Background" style="width:100%;">


<div class="bottom-left"></div>

<div class="top-left"></div>

<div class="top-right"></div>

<div class="bottom-right"></div>

</div>
<div class="centered">Computer Technology</div>
```

Here's my css

```
.bg-container {
border: 5px solid #D1270B; 

height:100%; 

box-sizing:border-box; 

width:100%;


}

.centered {
padding-top:2em;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code help you

- add css on website like

```
*{
 Padding:0;
 Margin:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add padding-bottom as you want to cover your border.
Also, you can remove this padding and make it positioned.

```
.centered {padding-top:2em;}
```